# LV Voltage controlled buffer with Hi-Z

Tags: buffer

I need to control one digital signal with another. I need hi-z when the control signal is low, and non-inverting buffer when the control signal is high. I'd like to do this with few parts as necessary, probably just fet based.

Logical table:

```
       S_Hi    S_Lo
C_Hi   Hi       Lo
C_Lo   Hi_Z     Hi_Z
```

My signals are in the 3V to 5V range.

I have a signal line that is multiplexed with a programming line. I thought the programmer would put its pins in a hi-z state, but it doesn't. Hence they hold the line low or high while not programming preventing the signal line from working properly. I have a control line that is high while the programming is working.

I'm not looking for something I'd have to order and wait a few days. It's not that big of a deal. I'm looking for a circuit I can throw together with what I have(mosfets, bjts, passives).

Comment: Too bad.  MOSFETs in discrete form aren't usually reliable switches at 3 to 5V, because (unlike logic circuits) they aren't specially designed for it.  Your 'what I have' list might have appropriate parts, CD4016 or 74HC125 or a host of others, but general purpose 'mosfets, bjts, passives' aren't easy building blocks for this kind of function.

Answer (score 2):

The [74LVC1G126](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74LVC1G126.pdf) is a single output inhibit buffer that has the behavior you're looking for. It is available in 5- or 6-pin packages and has 5V-tolerant inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified how much current this needs to provide.  If you don't need that much (~.1-50mA) this should be fine.

Really it's just a two stage version of the chip 74LVC1G126 posted by another user, built from individual MOS.

It's just a simple inverter (for polarity, since you wanted a buffer) into a tristate-inverter.  The tristate inverter requires c and c'.  When c=0, c'=1, and both M7 and M5 are off.  If c=1,c'=0, and so it functions like a normal inverter.

Or, if you have a transmission gate IC you could use that to provide a high-z control straight from S.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVgDI7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>